# Loading or triggering external script in an Email

Tags: php, email

Can we load external script in an email ?

Like we can trigger external script in inline css used in email for tracking views.

Example :

```
<td style=\"background:#ffffff url('http://domain.com/views.php?param=key') no-repeat; height:20px;\">&nbsp;</td>
```

But can we somehow load output of external script in an email when the email gets opened ?

Comment: Genearlly no.  Modern email clients won't permit this, thankfully. You can't even rely on that external image for tracking. Most modern clients won't load those either without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to load any external scripts.  You can load external images, but most (all) modern email clients don't download images by default.  The user must allow an email to display images.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  Some mail clients will allow `<iframe>` elements inside of HTML emails:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/

Of course, a lot of major clients (most notably:  Gmail and recent versions of Outlook) do not support this, so it's not a robust approach.

If you don't need to actually display any output from your PHP script in the e-mail (like if you're just trying to see if the message was opened by the recipient or something) then you might be able to get away with using an `<img>` tag that references your script.  However, many mail clients will not display such images unless the user clicks a "display unsafe images" button.  So again, it's not 100% reliable.  There probably is no 100% reliable way to do this.